# Sent cookies along with jQuery Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, web-services, jquery-mobile, cookies

I'm using following method to send jQuery Ajax request to .net powered web service. My cookies are being sent without any problem. But when I try to force refresh (Ctrl + F5) then cookies are omitted and request type also shown as `OPTION` not `GET`

```
$.ajax({            
 type: "GET",
 url: url,
 data: param,
 contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: successFunc,
 error: errorFunc,
 beforeSend:function(){$.mobile.loading('show');},
 complete:function(){$.mobile.loading('hide');}
});
```

My request is in Same domain so I hope same domain origin policy won't be a problem here.

Comment: are you doing cross-protocol ajax call? I mean the page having above `$.ajax` code gets served via HTTP and you are putting the `url` in it which points to the web service within your same domain but is accessible on HTTPS. In such case you may see `OPTION` request type instead of `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax( {

      //Just add this code 
       xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true 
       }

     });
```